# Using Powerpoint slides or background of poetry

Tags: copyright

I am using powerpoint slides (from Microsoft only) for use with poetry presentation on my [website](http://www.studybee.net). I often wonder if it is fair use of powerpoint presentation slides. Please guide me in this regard.

Another related question of mine would be the use of pictures of William Shakespeare (created in the 19th century) in a [website](http://www.risenotes.com) about English literature. Will the use of pictures of Shakespeare and other playwrights be fair?

And lastly, can I write reviews of copyrighted books while using their images/cover pages?

I understand Public domain means 65 years after the death of the creator/author is what makes a work of art available to all. But I am still confused over the above usages.

Comment: Please ask only one question. I you have more than one divide them into two or more separate questions on this site. Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: I'd suspect what you are doing does *not* fall under "fair use" as [defined by copyright.gov.](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html) Specifically, you are *not* using the work to comment on the work directly and are displaying it publicly. -- But I'm not a lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer so take this as you will, and I didn't look at your site nor will I. But Fair Use Copyright allows reproduction for educational purposes with proper citation and no intent to claim the work as your own or sell. It sounds like your literary website would fall into this category, but if you have any concerns then you need to contact an attorney with knowledge of patent and copyright laws.

Comment: Not only that, but it seems that the copyrights would've expired on much of the material in question anyway, can't say for sure due to the vagueness.